# Strange result of tf.nn.conv2d_backprop_filter

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

Following code is for examining the back propagation process for kernel(filter) weights of conv2d for CNN in tensorflow.
At first, I got the output of conv2d to check which elements of the input are used to produce the output.
tf.conv2d was called using 3X3 input, 1X1 kernel and stride 3.
Next, in the assumption that gradient of conv output is [[100]], I got the kernel gradient using the tf.nn.conv2d_backprop_filter function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder("float", [1,3,3,1])
k = tf.placeholder("float", [1,1,1,1])
g = tf.placeholder("float", [1,1,1,1])

tfconv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, k, strides=[1,3,3,1], padding='SAME', data_format='NHWC')
tfgrad = tf.nn.conv2d_backprop_filter(x, [1,1,1,1], g, strides=[1,3,3,1], padding='SAME', data_format='NHWC')

input = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]).reshape(1,3,3,1)
kernel = np.array([10]).reshape(1,1,1,1)
gradient = np.array([100]).reshape(1,1,1,1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    conv_tf = sess.run(tfconv, feed_dict={x:input, k:kernel})
    grad_tf = sess.run(tfgrad, feed_dict={x:input, g:gradient})

    print("inp = {}".format(input[0,:,:,0]))
    print("kernel = {}".format(kernel[:,:,0,0]))
    print("conv_tf = {}".format(conv_tf[0,:,:,0]))
    print("gradient = {}".format(gradient[0,:,:,0]))
    print("grad_tf = {}".format(grad_tf[0,:,:,0]))
```

The output is like below.

```
inp = [[1 2 3]
       [4 5 6]
       [7 8 0]]
kernel = [[10]]
conv_tf = [[50.]]
gradient = [[100]]
grad_tf = [[100.]]
```

In this test, we can find that grad_tf was computed using the input element 1 at position (0,0) instead of 5 at position (1,1) which had been used in the conv2d evaluation.
I am guessing that this is an error of tensorflow.
Of course, it may be a my mistake.
Can you let me know what is the reason of this problem?

I found this problem can make the training process of CNN very confusing like following case,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder("float", [1,3,3,1])

k_value = [10]
k_init = tf.constant_initializer(k_value)
k = tf.get_variable('k', shape=[1,1,1,1], initializer=k_init)

tfconv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, k, strides=[1,3,3,1], padding='SAME', data_format='NHWC')
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tfconv))

train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)

ocg = tf.gradients(cost, tfconv)
wcg = tf.gradients(cost, k)
wog = tf.gradients(tfconv, k)

input = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0], dtype="float32").reshape(1,3,3,1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    kv = sess.run(k)
    print("kernel before training = {}".format(kv[:,:,0,0]))

    cv, xv, kv, fv, g1, g2, g3, _ = sess.run([cost, x, k, tfconv, ocg, wcg, wog, train_op], feed_dict={x:input})

    print("cost = {}".format(cv))
    print("x = {}".format(xv[0,:,:,0]))
    print("conv = {}".format(fv[0,:,:,0]))
    print("conv-cost gradient = {}".format(np.asarray(g1)))
    print("kernel-cost gradient = {}".format(np.asarray(g2)))
    print("conv-cost gradient = {}".format(np.asarray(g3)))

    kv = sess.run(k)
    print("kernel after training = {}".format(kv[:,:,0,0]))
```

Following is the output and what is important is that kernel weight is really changed according to the wrong input value which was not used in the conv2d operation instead of the proper one.

```
kernel before training = [[ 10.]]
cost = 2500.0
x = [[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]
 [ 7.  8.  0.]]
conv = [[ 50.]]
conv-cost gradient = [[[[[ 100.]]]]]
kernel-cost gradient = [[[[[ 100.]]]]]
conv-cost gradient = [[[[[ 1.]]]]]
kernel after training = [[ 9.]]
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the query but have some confusions. Could you please explain: "we can find that grad_tf was computed using the input element 1 at position (0,0) instead of 5 at position (1,1) which had been used in the conv2d evaluation.", what do you mean by this?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, user3480922.
The kernel weight 10 was multiplied to some element of the input tensor and we can easily know that it is 5 in the center of input because the product is 50. So the gradient for the kernel weight 10 should be 500 which is the product of 5 and 100. But as the product is 100 as shown in grad_tf tf.nn.conv2d_backprop_filter is using the top-left element 1 in the input for the evaluation of kernel weight gradient.